# Unable to call function within a function called by addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, callback, filereader, addeventlistener

Basically I want to be able to load a configuration from a .csv file and use it to setup an HTML page. After some digging I found the common solution of a FileReader and an AddEventListener. My HTML looks like so :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="kernel.js"></script>
        <script>
            var k = new kernel();
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <input type="file" id="file-input" />
        <script>
            document.getElementById('file-input').addEventListener('change', k.loadConfig, false);
        </script>

        <!-- Tables and stuff that i want to modify -->

    </body>
</html>
```

kernel.js :

```
function kernel() {

    var self = this;
    this.config = null;

    this.readSingleFile = function(e) {

        var file = e.target.files[0];
        if (!file) return null;

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) { self.config = e.target.result; };
        reader.readAsText(file);

    }

    this.loadConfig = function(e) {

        self.readSingleFile(e);
        console.log(self.config);

        // Do more stuff 

    }

}
```

Then the console.log() should display the content of the file if I'm not mistaken. But instead it comes up null, and I'm stuck.

If someone can help me or even direct me in the right direction I would be really grateful.

Regards,
Dom.

Comment: You need to bind the correct context. In your kernel function, add `var self = this;` then use `var reader = self.readSingleFile(e);

Comment: My browser does not like `function kernel {` without the () either

Comment: PS: Next time please hit the `<>` button and create a [mcve]

Comment: `var kernel = new kernel();` <-- that seems like a bad idea using the same variable name.

Comment: renamed kernel variable to k, does not change anything. Added var self = this as shown (edited post) but now reader.result is null so I guess something is still not right .. must I return reader in readSingleFile() ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 1):

You are loosing execution context. You can fix it by binding `kernel.loadConfig` function to `kernel` object explicitly with [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
document.getElementById('file-input')
  .addEventListener('change', kernel.loadConfig.bind(kernel), false);
```

Using anonymous function as event handler will also work:

```
document.getElementById('file-input')
  .addEventListener('change', function() {
    kernel.loadConfig();
  }, false);
```